# How to take a screenshot showing the mouse cursor using Python?

Tags: python, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot of a game and show the custom cursor of the game inside of it.

I have tried D3Dshow library and couldn't get it to work.
and also tried pyscreenshot, which works but doesn't show the cursor on the screenshot.

I just need to take a screenshot of my entire screen/game showing the custom cursor.

Comment: Have you considered inserting an image of the mouse cursor at the current mouse location, into a screenshot without the cursor?

Comment: What i'm doing is basically taking a bunch of screenshots and make my program click whenever my cursor changes, thats why i need for the cursor to be shown on the screenshhot

Comment: there are other ways to check if the mouse has changed position, like with [pynput](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pynput/latest/pynput.pdf)...